# Simulation of a stadium entrance in AnyLogic

Tags: anylogic

We are simulating a stadium entrance in Anylogic, consisting of six turnstiles (which has been represented as queue lines) of which each turnstile can randomly stop functioning throughout the entire model time. How do we stop the people from going to those gates?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Find a Service Point (or Service Line) markup element that serves pedestrians from the queue. The element is embedded in another markup element — Service With Lines or Service With Points. This element has `setSuspended( boolean value )` function. If you call `setSuspended( true )`, the service point/line will not serve pedestrians until you call `setSuspended( false )`. You may do it with cyclic event, statechart or schedule.